# Async Task issue in Android

Tags: asynchronous, task

Trying to call async-Task for Multiple Files at a time

```
 case Type1:
            srcCopydir = Dir1
            copyfilename = file1;               
            copyFilesAsyncTask.execute(srcCopydir, copyfilename);
             break;  
         case Type2:              
            srcCopydir = Dir2
            copyfilename = file2;
            copyFilesAsyncTask.execute(srcCopydir, copyfilename);
            break;

        case Type3:
            srcCopydir = Dir3;
            copyfilename = file3
            copyFilesAsyncTask.execute(srcCopydir, copyfilename);
            break;

         case Type4:
            srcCopydir = Dir3;
            copyfilename = file3
            copyFilesAsyncTask.execute(srcCopydir, copyfilename);
            break;
```

Asysnc task for all these cases start one by one

"doInBackground" runs correctly and return the result correctly however sometimes while executing the asynctask before "onPostExecute" of one task is called "doInBackground" starts for another task

Hence onPostexecute returns the result of other task (e.g. Type2: Async task output is returned corresponding to Type 3  and Type3: Async task returns output expected for Type3)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new instance of your AsyncTask in every case. Something like this:

```
case Type1:
    srcCopydir = Dir1
    copyfilename = file1;               
    new YourAsyncTask().execute(srcCopydir, copyfilename);
    break;  
case Type2:              
    srcCopydir = Dir2
    copyfilename = file2;
    new YourAsyncTask().execute(srcCopydir, copyfilename);
    break;
case Type3:
    srcCopydir = Dir3;
    copyfilename = file3
    new YourAsyncTask().execute(srcCopydir, copyfilename);
    break;
case Type4:
    srcCopydir = Dir3;
    copyfilename = file3
    new YourAsyncTask().execute(srcCopydir, copyfilename);
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments but I am already creating the new instance of my Async Task for each case and it's not working

Comment: Can I ask you to post your AsyncTask, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      //preExecute
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        //Execution Code
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      if(yes){
        //Call new Task
        new NewTask().execute();
      }
    }
}
```